# How to select the contents of a DVD in the most space efficient way?

Tags: algorithm

I have these directories, A, B, C.. of various sizes that I need to burn on DVD. The thing is I don't want to waste any space. I want to pack this directories in the DVD as tightly as possible without any respect to order. But of course the contents of the directories aren't to be meddled with.

Eg: DVD is 4GB. A is 1GB, B is 2GB, C is 3GB, D is 2 GB.

Following the order I would need 3 DVDs as `{1: [A,B], 2: [C], 3: [D]}`

But the most efficient way would be 2 DVDs as `{1: [B, D], 2: [A,C]}`

Having a hard time as to where to start. Is there an algorithm already for this?

I am working on Python 3 but generic code is welcome.

Comment: smells like a bin packing problem. First Fit or Best Fit is your guy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem. A good read: https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2002/AAAI02-110.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is a Bin-Packing problem which is NP Hard so finding an exact answer will take a lot of time. You can use a simple knapsack algorithm but it's may not always be correct.
Here's a link which explains this in more detail.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bin-packing-problem-minimize-number-of-used-bins/